# TensorFlow 2.5 random set seed not working , Giving an Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
```

---

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 tf.random.set_seed(1234)
> 2 print(tf.random.uniform([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2JtV.png), seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
> 3 print(tf.random.uniform([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2JtV.png), seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
> 4 tf.random.set_seed(1234)
> 5 print(tf.random.uniform([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2JtV.png), seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I just copied the Example code from the TensorFlow docs to check it. But it also gave me the same error. I run the code in colab.

Comment: You mean the above code produces TypeError? If so, I ran it and it worked normally!

Comment: Now It's working, I just Factory reset In the Colab and Now the Code is working

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Generally you will get above error, if you have assigned some `integer` to `tf.random.set_seed` and tried to execute above code in the same session caused this issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed=1234

tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5e2ffd56d477> in <module>()
      3 tf.random.set_seed=1234
      4 
----> 5 tf.random.set_seed(1234)
      6 print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
      7 print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

**Fixed code:**

You should remove `tf.random.set_seed=1234` and restart your kernel has solve the issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1))  # generates 'A2'
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([0.1689806], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.7539084], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.1689806], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.7539084], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```